# Upgrade to rspec 3 cause error when using should have(1).error_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

Since I updated my Gemfile and moved to rspec 3, in many tests, I'm getting a error for: way:

```
it "should reject attribute that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 3
      hash = @attr.merge(:details => short)
      Deal.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:details)
    end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: Deal.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:details)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `have' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Deal_2::TestsOnDealsModelsValidations>
```

I read I should now be using "expect" instead of should but here with `have(1).error_on`, how should I write it to comply with rspec 3?

I tried the following but it still does not work:

```
it "should reject attribute that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 3
      hash = @attr.merge(:details => short)
      expect(Deal.new(hash).error_on(:details).size).to eq(1)
    end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have replaced the likes of

```
Deal.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:details)
```

with

```
deal = Deal.new(hash)
expect(deal.valid?).to be_falsey
expect(deal.errors[:details].size).to eq(1)
```

The first expectation with `valid?` is necessary as it initializes the `errors` list.

Answer (score 8):

`have` and other similar matchers have been moved out of rspec core and into another gem, [rspec-collection-matchers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers).

I recommend following the upgrade path from rspec 2 -> 3 as detailed in the rspec docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/docs/upgrade

- Upgrade to rspec 2.99
- Run your test suite
- Fix deprecation warnings
- Upgrade to rspec 3.

If you had done this you would have received a deprecation error with your code that would have also told you what to do to fix it.

Comment: Just add in your Gemfile: gem "rspec-collection-matchers".

Answer (score 1):

The line to add to your `Gemfile` should be:

```
gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
```